# Am I able to change a line of code with another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a little game on unity and I have reached a problem. I want a ball to go up and hit a wall when the screen is tapped and then the movement reverses and then if you tap after the ball has collided with the top wall, it goes down and hits the bottom wall and reverses and so on. My problem here is that I don't know how I can get the movement to reverse.

Here is the player movement script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: You just need a variable to flag which direction you're going and then an if/else block to choose which bit of code to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new field for the direction. As long as you want only two directions (up and down) a float suffices.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public float direction = 1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce * direction;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * 0;
        direction *= -1f;
    }

}
```

Coded by heart. 
You might also want to consider making your fields private if no other objects access them.